# Creating Multiple rewrite rules does not accept one parameter

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this .htaccess file and it works fine:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?
locale=$1&section=$2&action=$3&id=$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?locale=$1&section=$2&action=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?locale=$1&section=$2 [L]
```

But when I add one more line, for one single parameter it explodes. This is the final file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?
locale=$1&section=$2&action=$3&id=$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?locale=$1&section=$2&action=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?locale=$1&section=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.php?locale=$1 [L]
```

And this is the error message:

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@mydomain.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your server error log will have something like,

> Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

This happens when mod_rewrite finishes processing a URL and then hands it back to the URL parser which then performs rewrite rules again on it, even though you had those darn `[L]` flags on it the first time. Those first 3 patterns don't match any of each other but that last one matches itself.

For what you appear to be doing, which is prettifying URLs, probably the easiest way to handle this is to simply ignore paths that begin with index.php for that last rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?locale=$1&section=$2&action=$3&id=$4
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?locale=$1&section=$2&action=$3
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?locale=$1&section=$2
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.php?locale=$1
```